# Android custom View: how to make Drawables survive rotation?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I am creating an Android custom `View` that allows the user to set a `Drawable` using both resource id and an instance of a `Drawable` itself.

The problem is that after a configuration change (eg: change of orientation), the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated and, with it, also my custom `View`.

For everything that is parcelable I am using the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods, so no problem to save the `DrawableRes` id, but a generic `Drawable` instance is not parcelable nor serializable.

The `Drawable` I want to save is really small, it is just 24x24 dp.

I thought about converting the `Drawable` to `Bitmap`, that is parcelable, but I would loose the support of of most of the subclasses, like `AnimatedVectorDrawable` and `LayerDrawable`.